# Count ones in BitVec in Z3 with Datalog input format

Tags: z3, datalog

Is there a compact way of counting the number of bits that are set to 1 in a BitVec in Z3 using Datalog input format?

```
$ z3 -h  # most of the lines below omited for clarity
Input format:
  -dl         use parser for Datalog input format.
```

The currently accepted answer for this question: [Count ones in BitVec in Z3 with SMT 2 input format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137675/count-ones-in-bitvec-in-z3-with-smt-2-input-format) states that there is no nice way to do in SMT 2 input format.

The currently accepted answer for this question: [Sum of all the bits in a Bit Vector of Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299015/sum-of-all-the-bits-in-a-bit-vector-of-z3) shows how to do this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For `32 bit` vectors, you could try to translate the following pseudo code to SMT:

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24; // count
```

This is called [Bit Twiddling Hack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) and was also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/1911064).

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed an interesting idea to use this hack in order to reduce the amount of boilerplate code. (Nevertheless, this question is about Datalog input format.)